# a newbie friendly asdf (another system definition facility) user guide

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

I am currently trying to get a grasp on [asdf](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/), but sadly (but apparently not [uncommonly](http://smuglispweeny.blogspot.de/2008/12/beginners-guide-to-asdf-ha.html)) the standard user guide is not really of any help, as it does explain (I guess) the relevant parts but misses to distribute some extended examples containing comments, so a newbie can see those commands in action.

I am especially interested in the usage of `:defsystem-depends-on` and the `:components`
part of the `defsystem` syntax.

Therefore the question is: **Is there a more sophisticated and newbie-friendly user guide for asdf out there than the standard user guide?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't have time to write a comprehensive tutorial (and I don't have a comprehensive understanding), but I *can* provide a link & copy from a project I have.

```
(asdf:defsystem #:cl-yahoo-finance
  :depends-on ( #:drakma #:babel #:cl-csv #:yason #:url-rewrite)
  :components ((:file "cl-yahoo-finance"))  ;;cl-yahoo-finance is cl-yahoo-finance.lisp, in the same directory.
  :name "cl-yahoo-finance"
  :version "3.2"
  :maintainer "Paul Nathan"
  :author "Paul Nathan"
  :licence "LLGPL"
  :description "CL interface to Yahoo's finance API"
  :long-description "Common Lisp interface to Yahoo's finance API, available over the web. See usage.lisp for example code.")
```

https://github.com/pnathan/cl-yahoo-finance/blob/master/cl-yahoo-finance.asd

Comment: thank you for the supplied link I looked through it and it helped a bit to get some sort of understanding, but the overall picture is still blurry

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific questions?

`:defsystem-depends-on` is just some systems which must be loaded before the system definition is processed. From the grammar you can see that a system name is either a string or a symbol.

`:components` - many uses are relatively simple. For example it would list a bunch of files.

See also the [grammar of ASDF DEFSYSTEM.](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#The-defsystem-grammar)

Comment: not as simple, for example how does the list of defsystem-depends-on look like, strings? How does the modules part of components look like, what are the effects of the method you apparently can define within those modules.
I got a lot of questions on my heart and it would be too much for here, this is y I ended up asking for a guide.

Comment: @Sim, the grammar that Rainer points to _does_ make this clear.  `:defsystem-depends-on` is followed by a `system-list`, which is defined as a list of `simple-component-name`s, which are specified as either strings or symbols.  The manual isn't great, but there's more there than you give it credit for.

Comment: i do not deny any credit, it just happens that I am a newbie using ASDF and the guide is not of much help if you are more experienced it probably is a great reference.