# How to load external dependencies with quicklisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

Here is my code:

```
(defpackage :com.yves.tests (:use :common-lisp))
(in-package :com.yves.tests)
(require :usocket)
```

Everytime I evaluate the `require` directive, I get this error:

```
LOAD: A file with name #1=USOCKET does not exist
   [Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR]
```

Of course I installed the package with quickload in my REPL:

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "usocket")
To load "usocket":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    usocket
; Loading "usocket"

("usocket")
CL-USER>
```

Actually I've installed it yesterday evening, and all my code was evaluating with no complain. Today I restarded Emacs and Slime. And I get this error. Is there additional configuration to do?

Here is what is in my loadpath:

```
CL-USER> (princ custom:*load-paths*)
(/Users/yves/quicklisp/ /opt/local/lib/clisp-2.49/dynmod/ ./ ~/lisp/**/)
(#P"/Users/yves/quicklisp/" #P"/opt/local/lib/clisp-2.49/dynmod/" #P"./"
 "~/lisp/**/")
CL-USER>
```

Am I supposed to add the path to every new package by hand? Isn't quicklisp initialisation supposed to perform it, by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Require` is not the required operation here.

In the simple case where you have your entire system in one self-sufficient file, you can wrap `ql:quickload` forms into an `eval-when`:

```
(in-package #:cl-user)

(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "usocket"))

(defpackage #:com.yves.tests
  (:use #:cl))

(in-package #:com.yves.tests)

;; your code here
```

If you want to use symbols from `usocket` without qualification, use it in the defpackage form:

```
(defpackage #:com.yves.tests
  (:use #:cl #:usocket))
```

If you have a bigger system that spans several files, you can use ASDF.  A quick way to get a simple setup running is `quickproject`, also available from Quicklisp.

Comment: Pretty amazing since your first proposition is working. Yesterday I was using the second one. After starting Emacs this morning, it was printing the error shown in my question. I fiddled a little bit and removed it from the ``:use`` directive and replaced it with the require. I think I will need to go deeper into the lisp's namespace comprehension.. Thnx again.

Comment: Can anyone explain what is the difference between `#:packagename` and simple `:packagename`? I saw both versions but don't know the difference.

Comment: @dptd: `Defpackage` takes _string designators_ in most places (see glossary in CLHS).  Any symbol is also a string designator of its name.  At read time, `symbol` gets or creates (effectively) a symbol interned into the current package, `:symbol` gets or creates a symbol interned into the KEYWORD package, and `#:symbol` always creates a fresh uninterned symbol.  By using the last form, you avoid all unnecessary interning when all you care about is the name.  This is a rather minor optimization, so some people even just use plain symbols here, since that looks cleaner in the source file.

Answer (score 3):

Svante already answered a basic solution to your question, but it might be more comfortable to use quicklisp in combination with asdf (and an .asd file) to be able to expand the project and its requirements more easily.

Your setup for the .asd file would probably look like:

```
;;foobar.asd
(asdf:defsystem :foobar ;this is the name of your project
   :depends-on (:usocket) ;those are the names of the dependencies
   :components ((:file "the-file-name"))) ;this .asd has to be in the same folder (asdf-keyword :module)
```

After defining your foobar.asd you'll either move the project into the [.quicklisp/local-project/](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/faq.html) (a symlink will do) folder or you tell [asdf how to find your project](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuring-ASDF).

Now you should be able to load your project via `(ql:quickload :foobar)`

From now on asdf/quicklisp will take care of (down)loading all defined dependencies before loading your project.

If you later want to extend your project and therefore your projects .asd file, you can find valueable information at the [asdf manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Defining-systems-with-defsystem) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980883/a-newbie-friendly-asdf-another-system-definition-facility-user-guide/10984452#10984452). The project page for asdf can be visited [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/).